# What is i+++ increment in c++

Tags: c++, operators, increment

can anyone tell me what is the process of i+++ increment in c++.

Comment: You really mean three plus signs and not two?

Comment: @john: I meant +++ and I'm fully aware of conventional c++ and increment operators.

Comment: @BC: That's cool. Just checking.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It is a syntax error.

Using the [maximum munching rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximal_munch) `i+++` is tokenized as:

```
i ++ +
```

The last `+` is a binary addition operator. But clearly it does not have two operands which results in parser error.

**EDIT:**

Question from the comment: Can we have `i++++j` ?

It is tokenized as:

```
i ++ ++ j
```

which again is a syntax error as `++` is a unary operator.

On similar lines `i+++++j` is tokenized by the scanner as:

```
i++ ++ + j
```

which is same as `((i++)++) + j` which again in error as `i++` is not a lvalue and using `++` on it is not allowed.

Answer (score 17):

`i+++;` will not compile. There is no operator +++ in C++.

`i+++j`, on the other hand, will compile. It will add i and j and then increment i. Because it is parsed as `(i++)+j`;

Comment: Also note that it'll throw away the result of `i+j` unless you assign it as well.

Comment: @Mark B: If I were you, I'd use the term `throw` with caution as far as C++ is concerned. Took me a couple of seconds to understand you aren't talking about exceptions :)

Comment: actually I am talking about 3 "+" signs that is +++, and want to know their significance.

Comment: there is no question about exceptions or SEH handlers, I was just asking about the "munching rule" which of of u have specified. You mentioned the first line , which I think I am aware and was naive, but thnx for your replies.

Answer (score 1):

if you mean `i++` then its incrementing the value of `i` once its value has been read.
As an example:

```
int i = 0;   // i == 0
int j = i++; // j == 0, i == 1
```